# How can I remove the blank space below japanese characters?

Tags: html, css, special-characters

I have some code hosted [here](https://yrrah2.github.io/learnSite/japanese/). When you highlight the character it has a large empty space below it which covers the input box meaning it is hard to click on the input box. This issue persists when the character is not highlighted.

I have tried many methods including changing line-height, changing position values, changing the height of the div, all to no avail.

Is there a way to make the area of the character smaller?

[image: character highlighted][image: character normal]

I have made a code snippet to show the problem here:

```css
#character {
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 20em;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: beige;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><span id="character">い</span></div>
<span><input value="try to click me"></span>
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the problem. The highlight works just fine for me (i.e. it doesn't cover up the `input` element). Also, it is very recommended for you to post a minimal example here to help others understand where the problem is specifically (e.g. now, I can't replicate your problem). Do take a look at how to create a minimal, reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added a code snippet to show what the issue is. The colour highlights below the input however you cannot click the input. If you double click the input you can see it highlights the character

Answer (score 1):

CSS line height, check out the fiddle I inserted. make sure you don't have an overriding css rule that is cascading down. Add some padding to the top for the adjustment of line height if needed.

```css
#w_lineheight {
  padding-top: 4px;
  line-height: .9em; 
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

#no_lineheight {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="w_lineheight">
    あ か ば ぱ ま や わ  ---- added lineheight of .9em
</div>
<div id="no_lineheight">
    さ ざ た だ な は ら  ---- No lineheight added here
</div>
```